# Jquery Validation example not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to test a very basic jquery validation example. the code is as follows:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo"/>
</form>​
```

My JS code:

```
$('#foo').validate({
    foo: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
    }
});​
```

That doesn't work...
Any help or working examples will be appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do the `.validate()` call on the `<form>`, and name the properties of the validation configuration after the field names?  Your field is called "foo", not "name".

Answer (score 2):

You use the `validate` method on your **form**, not in a single element, and all the rules should be inside the `rules` property, like:

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        foo: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        }
    }
});
```

a live example can be [found in JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ipetog/2/edit).

Answer (score 2):

Call the `validate` method at the form and wrap the rules in a `rules` obejct. If you want add an `messages` object.

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        foo: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        }
    },
    messages: {
       foo: "Please enter your foo"
   }
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/a7xNX/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#commentForm").validate({
        rules: {
            txtPhNumber: "required",
            txtPhNumber2:
                {
            equalTo: "#txtPhNumber"
                }
            }
        });
    });

  </script>
```